# Phusion Passenger running with Fullstaq Ruby

Tags: ruby, passenger

We're trying to use an apt-installed version of [Fullstaq](https://github.com/fullstaq-ruby/server-edition) Ruby with Passenger and Nginx on Ubuntu 20.04 installed via the recommended process from [the Passenger website](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/tutorials/deploy_to_production/installations/oss/aws/ruby/nginx/).  We specifically do not want to compile Nginx to work with Passenger.

The problem we're running into is that the passenger apt package depends on Ruby and apt doesn't recognize the Ruby installs from the Fullstaq repository as valid options to meet that dependency.

We've come "close" by configurating passenger options as:

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /usr/lib/fullstaq-ruby/versions/2.7-jemalloc/bin/ruby;
```

But passenger still boots using the default OS provided Ruby rather than the specific version we install from the Fullstaq repo.  A subset of the installed packages can be found here:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep ruby
ii  fullstaq-ruby-2.7-jemalloc         10-ubuntu-20.04                   amd64        Fullstaq Ruby 2.7-jemalloc
ii  fullstaq-ruby-common               1.0-0                             all          Fullstaq Ruby common dependencies
ii  ruby2.7                            2.7.0-5ubuntu1.7                  amd64        Interpreter of object-oriented scripting language Ruby
ii  ruby                               1:2.7+1                           amd64        Interpreter of object-oriented scripting language Ruby (default version)
```

Has anyone found a successfully configuration to make Fullstaq Ruby and Passenger work together?

Comment: Did you resolve this. If so please update with the answer. I am running into the same issue.

Comment: If feels dirty, but this configuration point to the shims worked for us:


    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/ruby;

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment, I ended up just adding the following to the sites nginx config

```
passenger_ruby /home/<username>/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```